# gwan. Accessing site through external IP

Tags: webserver, ip-address, g-wan

I have a Gwan server set up at home on my Arch Linux box.  I'm running "motion".  I have a router that, of course, handles my external IP address.

I want to access the avi movie shorts generated by motion through port 1000 which is port forwarded through my router to the box on my internal network.  I've written an event_end script that copies these motion videos to my Gwan "Document Root". I've set the particular directory up according to the Gwan docs and can see these videos using the external ip address:1000 just fine when I'm at home.  But when I click on the very same link from the machine at my office, I get this error message in Firefox: "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 99.99.99.99:1000.".

So I don't understand why I can see that link when I'm at home but not from anyplace else.  What setting have I missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your firewall at work allows traffic on port :1000 at all?

Comment: I presume so.  I switched to Gwan from quickserve because the Arch version of quickserve hasn't been updated for 2 or 3 months.  But while I was using quickserve, I could view those videos just fine while using port:1000.

Answer (score 0):

> port 1000 which is port forwarded through my router to the box on my internal network [at home]... but I get an error *"Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 99.99.99.99:1000"* [from my office].

As Pete noticed, this sounds like a routing error.

As the HTTP client, Firefox, cannot even establish a connection, the problem happens before G-WAN can do anything.

> while I was using quickserve, I could view those videos just fine while using port:1000

...probably from your private network at home, and not from your office.

If quickserve was available from your office then, since then, you have messed with the router port mapping OR with the G-WAN listener (hence the connection failure).

Unfortunately, since G-WAN won't receive anything until you get this right, its log files won't help.

And as you do not provide any information about your port mapping and G-WAN listener, we can't help you to spot obvious errors.

Note that this issue is a system configuration problem and has little to do with the G-WAN application server itself (remember that Stackoverflow is a Q&A site for developers). The Serverfault site might be a better place to discuss your problem.